# flex and bison not able to detect error

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

flex and bison are not correctly detecting an error. It should be able to detect a closing bracket but no opening opening bracket. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

This is my bison file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
extern yylex();
extern yytext[];
%}
%start   start
%token   num att rel Lbracket Rbracket comma
%%
start                   : one_relation_expression {printf("ACCEPT\n"); exit(0);} ;
one_relation_expression : projection {printf("16 in .y\n");};
term                    : relation {printf("20 in .y\n");};                                                                                 
projection              : term {printf("23\n");}                                     
                        | term Lbracket attribute_commalist Rbracket {printf("24\n");};
attribute_commalist     : attribute {printf("25 in .y\n");}                              
                        | attribute comma attribute_commalist {printf("26 in .y\n");};
attribute               : att  {printf("34 in .y\n");};
relation                : rel  {printf("35 in .y\n");};
%%
yyerror()
{
   printf("REJECT\n");
   exit(0);
}
yywrap()
{
}
 main()
{
   yyparse();
   //printf("ACCEPT\n");
}
```

This is my flex file:

```
%{
#include "test.tab.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
extern int yylval;
%}
    /* patterns */
Delimiter    [ \t]
WhiteSpace   {Delimiter}+
Letter       [A-Za-z]
Digit        [0-9]
%%
    /* actions */
[0-9]       {
            yylval = atoi(yytext);
            return(num);
            }
"["         {return(Lbracket);}
"]"         {return(Rbracket);}
","         {return(comma);}
CNO         {return(att);}
CUST        {return(rel);}
.  ;
%%
/*int yywrap(void)
{
    return 1;
}*/
```

This is my test file:

```
CUST CNO]
```

It should be able to detect a closing bracket but no opening opening bracket.

Output:

```
$ ./p5 < a5.txt
35 in .y
20 in .y
23
16 in .y
ACCEPT
```

Comment: And what does it do instead?

Comment: It seems like `CUST` satisfied the one_relation_expression rule. And since there is no statement delimiter, the only problem you're likely to have is too much stuff. What is it doing? Do you have an output capture?

Comment: @EJP I have two printf statements. One for accept and one for reject. It accepts it instead of rejecting it.

Comment: @AustinHastings I added the output.

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing requiring the file to end when the grammar does, so it simply accepts the simplest case match. You might try forcing some kind of end-marker into the grammar: a statement delimiter, newline, or EOF marker.

Comment: No, you have several `printf()` calls. What else does it print? Is it a secret?

Comment: @EJP I added the output at the bottom.